# Generate web service client secure policy from .wsdl for java

Tags: java, soap, digital-signature, ws-security, encryption-symmetric

I have been researching how to implement a web service client policies from a .wsdl file.

The policies of the web services implicates a signature and encryption using a .jks file with the necessary keys (asymmetric privateKey for signing, and a symmetric privateKey for encryption). The policy is: **username:oracle/wss10_username_token_with_message_protection_service_policy**.

I am able to make the .xsd files (request, response and service objects) using the wsimport tool for java (or with cxf or axis2). What i can't resolve is how to make the correct policy.

Is there any way to automatically generate the policies from the .wsdl or do i have to make them by myself

Comment: Just to clarify: do you already have WS-SecurityPolicy annotations in your .wsdl or not? (In which case, if you are using CXF, your CXF client can take the wsdl with policies directly as input, no need to make new policy file on client side, only a config file with client-specific properties, e.g. username, password callback, etc.)

Comment: Of course there are Ws-SecuryPolicy.

Comment: OK, then why would you need to generate or make policies if they *are* already in your WSDL (in WS-SecurityPolicy format)? Apache CXF clients can take your WSDL with the policies (must be WS-SecurityPolicy 1.1 or later) as input directly for configuring security. Then you just need to specify the extra client-specific properties like username, password (callback), keys, etc.

Comment: See my answer for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username:oracle/wss10_username_token_with_message_protection_service_policy is solved with spring ws this way:

```
<!-- == Ougoing interceptor == -->
<bean id="loginOutgoingWss4jSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securementActions" value="Timestamp Signature Encrypt" />

    <!--  == Set Outgoing Signature properties == -->
    <property name="securementUsername" value="alias"/>
    <property name="securementPassword" value="aliasPass"/>
    <property name="securementSignatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
    <property name="securementSignatureCrypto" ref="cryptoFactoryBean" />
    <property name="securementSignatureParts" value="{Element}{}Body;{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;" />

    <!--  == Set Outgoing Encryption properties == -->
    <property name="securementEncryptionUser" value="alias"/> 
    <property name="securementEncryptionCrypto" ref="cryptoFactoryBean" />
    <property name="securementEncryptionKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
    <property name="securementEncryptionParts" value="{Content}{}Body;" />
</bean>

<!-- == Incoming interceptor == -->
 <bean id="loginIncomingWss4jSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="validationActions" value="Timestamp Signature Encrypt" />

    <!--  == Set Validations Response, This validate signature and decrypts response == -->
    <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />

    <!-- The lower operation validation. Less time consume-->
    <property name="validateRequest" value="false" />
    <property name="enableSignatureConfirmation" value="false"/>

    <!--  == Set Incoming Signature/Decryption keystore == -->
    <property name="validationDecryptionCrypto" ref="cryptoFactoryBean" />
    <property name="validationSignatureCrypto" ref="cryptoFactoryBean" />

    <!-- Sets the {@link org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback} handler to use when validating messages -->
    <property name="validationCallbackHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.callback.KeyStoreCallbackHandler">
            <property name="privateKeyPassword" value="aliasPass"/>
        </bean>
    </property> 
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using policies in WS-SecurityPolicy (1.1 or later) in your wsdl, no need to generate policies nor make them on client side with Apache CXF. With WS-SecurityPolicy, CXF's security runtime is policy driven.

1) You follow CXF's WSDL-first approach to generate the client code, using either `wsdl2java` command-line tool or Maven `cxf-codegen-plugin` (wsdl2java goal). This is described in CXF doc's [*How to develop a client*](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html).

2) Following CXF's doc on [WS-SecurityPolicy usage](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html), you configure the client security properties for the  wsdl port you want to use, either using JAX-WS API (on the client's `RequestContext`) or Spring XML configuration. For the list of possible properties, there are the generic [XML security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/security-configuration.html) ones and [WS-Security-specific](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html) ones. Example with Spring XML for UsernameToken policy (from [Glen Mazza's blog samples](https://github.com/gmazza/blog-samples/blob/master/cxf_ut_messagelayer/client/src/main/resources/cxf.xml) ):

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
   http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
<jaxws:client name="{http://www.example.org/contract/DoubleIt}DoubleItPort" createdFromAPI="true">
        <!-- Use this for the UsernameToken Symmetric Binding w/X.509 for secret key derivation -->
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="ws-security.username" value="alice"/>        
            <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value="client.ClientPasswordCallback"/>        
            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value="clientKeystore.properties"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="myservicekey"/>
        </jaxws:properties>

        <!-- Use this for the UsernameToken Symmetric Binding w/UT password for secret key derivation -->
        <!--jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="ws-security.username" value="alice"/>        
            <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value="client.ClientPasswordCallback"/>        
        </jaxws:properties-->
</jaxws:client>
</beans>
```

Put this in `/cxf.xml` on the class path. Warning: the example is using a `CallbackHandler` subclass ([client.ClientPasswordCallback](https://github.com/gmazza/blog-samples/blob/master/cxf_ut_messagelayer/client/src/main/java/client/ClientPasswordCallback.java) in this example) to provide the password. So you'll need to provide your own implementation.

3) Back to CXF doc's [*How to develop a client*](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html#DevelopingaConsumer-Clientmainfunction) - last part - in the application code, initialize the client using JAX-WS API with arguments: a) the location of the WSDL (URL) *having the WS-SecurityPolicy policies* (you already have that, as far as I understand); b) service and port's QNames to be used by the client, as defined in the WSDL:

```java
final Service service = Service.create(wsdlLocation, SERVICE_QNAME);
final DoubleItPortType transportPort = service.getPort(PORT_QNAME, DoubleItPortType.class);
```

4) Make sure you have `cxf-rt-ws-policy` and `cxf-rt-ws-security` modules on the classpath at runtime to enable WS-SecurityPolicy support.